# WP8 apps over HTTPS failure over the last weekend

Tags: windows-phone-8, https, ssl-certificate

Everybody, We have released two WP8 apps that communicating with our backend server over HTTPS. We bought and installed the SSL certificate for HTTPS from Entrust. The 2 WP8 apps worked very well before May 30 but failed suddenly this week.The 2 WP8 apps reported HTTP 404 error this week. At the same time our Android and iOS apps that communicating with the same backend server over HTTPS have worked well before and are working well this week. It is weird. We suspect there is some change from Microsoft side on SSL,security policy, etc. But we, as formal WP developers,didn't receive any formal change notification from Microsoft and searched internet without getting any useful clue. Pls help and advice if you have experienced the same weird HTTPS issue with WP8 apps.By the way, I am contacting Microsoft now and haven't gotten any useful feedback yet. Thanks a lot!